# Demonstrate that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Question:** A different point $M$ is taken from the endpoints on the small arc $AC$ of the circumcircle of a triangle $ABC$ satisfying the condition $|AB|=|AC|$. where $[BM]$ intersects $[AC]$ is $E$, the interior bisector of angle $BMC$ intersects $[BC]$ with $F$, $m(\widehat{AFB}) =m(\widehat{CFE})$ equality is achieved. Show that triangle $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

**Drawn version:** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPYjb.png)

**Here's what I've tried so far to tackle the problem:** I first extended [MF] and combined it with $A$, and then I applied the trigonometric answer theorem to two triangles with umbilical points $E$ and $F$, and I got nothing. I have a feeling I should make better use of the $m(\widehat{AFB}) =m(\widehat{CFE}) $information, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Consider figure; CI and BJ are altitudes of ANC. Using the fact that  in triangle BMC the bisector of angle BMC meets the perpendicular bisector of BC at point G , so AG is diameter of circumcircle and it is also the altitude of ABC. We have:

$\angle BMC=\angle BAC$

$\angle GMC=\angle GAC$

We mirror the construction about BC, so K and G are mirror os A and H respectively. We have:

$\angle HBC=\angle HKC=\frac{\overset{\large \frown}{HC}}2$

$\angle GAC=\frac{\overset{\large \frown}{GC}}2$

$\overset{\large \frown}{HC}=\overset{\large \frown}{GC}$

$\Rightarrow \angle HBC=\angle HAC$

$ \angle HKC=\angle HAC=\angle HKB\space\space\space\space (1)$

$\angle GBA=90^o$

Because it is opposite to diameter AG, so AB is tangent to bottom circle centered at G. So we have:

$ \angle ABH=\angle BKH\space\space\space\space (2)$

Summing (1) and (2) we get:

$\angle ABH+\angle HBC=\angle HAC+\angle HAB$

OR:

$\angle ABC=\angle BAC=\angle ACB$

that is triangle is equilateral.

Comment: At the end of the answer, I unbonneted. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @MuhammetYAĞCIOĞLU, You'r welcome.